# jQuery toggle sets display to different value than initially set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `label` which I want to show and hide via [.toggle( )](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). The label has a class `.hidden` which sets it to `display: none;` by default. Also it has following other CSS:

```
label { 
  color: #4d4d4d;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

for some reason, when I click on the toggle event handler, the label shows up, but with `display: inline;`, which is what I don't want, since I set it to `block`. This behaviour is only happening, when the label is set to `display: none;` intially. If the label is visible by default, it works as expected. Any chance I can toggle to the CSS set value?

Please note that I wanna use `.toggle()` not `.toggleClass()` or similar.

Comment: before or after your toggle you can change the property of your css using jquery $(.label).css('display', 'block');

Comment: @maku but as I said before, I'm already setting `display: block` in my CSS, so why is not taking it?

Comment: Post the code you're using and a minimum example, the behaviour can not be reproduced as `toggle` should store the display value and reset it back -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/anhx08n6/

Comment: @adeneo alright, one sec!

Comment: you can set if after you toggle, remove the default. its the same
if ($('#my-block').is(':visible'))
        $('#my-block').css('display','inline-block');

Comment: @maku too much code for such a simple thing

Comment: yah i have read something http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11436

Comment: @adeneo can't reproduce

Comment: @supersize same issue you encountered?

Comment: Not sure what that means or how that bug is relevant, but it should go without saying that if the element is initially hidden by a parent element being display `none`, the element to toggle would also have a computed initial display value of `none` so there's no way jQuery can know that it's supposed to be anything but the default value when toggled to visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toggle gives the default display value to label that is `inline`. You could hide label inside jquery to get the appropriate result.

> The matched elements will be revealed or hidden immediately, with no
>   animation, by changing the CSS display property. If the element is
>   initially displayed, it will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown.
>   The display property is saved and restored as needed. If an element
>   has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once
>   again be displayed inline.

```js
$("label").hide();
$("div").click(function() {
  $("label").toggle();
});
```

```css
label { 
  color: #4d4d4d;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>test label</label>

<div>toggle label</div>
```

Reference: [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) - [MDN - Inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente).